# Is there somewhere to buy used Latvian books in Riga?

Tags: shopping, latvia, riga, baltic-region

I'm finally travelling in the Baltics and hoping to add to my collection of translations of a certain famous novel that I collect. As a booklover and as a person on a miniscule budget, I like to dig around in secondhand bookshops for them.

In Tallinn I found a good bookshop in the old town with used books, and one of the major new bookshops even had a used section. Also in the old central market there were people trying to sell junk including mostly old Russian books.

But here in Riga even though there's a few new bookshops around, I've only found one thrift shop with a book section, and one language bookshop with new and used books, plus some stalls in the underpasses near the station which I think only have Russian books. Nothing to compare with Tallinn. But Riga is also much bigger so it'd be easier to miss them here.

In particular, the central market here is very big, but has also been renovated. I couldn't find books there but may have missed them.

Maybe there's even some weekly or monthly flea market?

Comment: By "Latvian books", do you mean books published in Latvia, or books published in Latvian? I'm asking because the Russian language was prevalent during the Soviet era in Latvia, so it only makes sense that you'll come across lots of old books written in Russian, even though they might've been written and published in Latvia.

Comment: @undercatsupportsMonica: I want a book in the Latvian language, and maybe an English-Latvian dictionary if I find one cheap and small. I added the Russian book to my collection years ago in Armenia and Russian dictionaries are pretty common. New books in Russian are still very common here now by the way.

Comment: Hesitant to write it as an answer because I've had no first hand experience with it, but an acquaintance of mine suggested [Antikvariāts PLANĒTA](http://www.antikvariatsplaneta.lv/eng/contacts/). It appears that two major antique book stores (at Dzirnavu and Riharda Vāgnera) have closed down recently.

Comment: @undercatsupportsMonica: Sometimes Antiquariats only have expensive collectible books, and sometimes they have all kinds of used books. Seems to vary by country. I'll check on this one thanks!

Comment: From what I gather they focus on at least 50 year old books. Not sure whether or not that is what you are after.